# adding event to list of controls that are created programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I'm generating a list of image controls in WPF .

```
  Image img = new Image();
                    img.Source = GetPic(value);
                    img.Tag = cst.GetIdDriverde();
                    img.ToolTip = dtID.Rows[j][0];
                    img.Width = 130;
                    img.Height = 130;
                    lst.Add(img);
```

I want to add an event to each control.
How can I do that?

Comment: You should not create Image elements in code, but instead use an ItemsControl with an Image element in its ItemTemplate. Besides that, to *which* event are you going to attach a handler?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mighty and Omid but if you run stubborn, here's a lambda

`img.MouseLeftButtonUp += (se, a) => {/*YOUR CODE*/};`

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an event like you do it for any other object.

For example a `MouseLeftButtonDown` event.

```
Image img = new Image();
img.MouseLeftButtonDown += Img_MouseLeftButtonDown;

private void Img_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    //your logic
}
```

Have a look at the [Image Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.image(v=vs.110).aspx) for the available events.

**Hint**

This would work but you should not add images like this at all. The better way would be to use a `ItemsControl` and using a `DataTemplate`. If you want to change your code let me know if you need some help.